# How to run/call a shell script function with graphicsmagick

Tags: shell, sh, graphicsmagick

I have a pdf of LaTeX math tasks which I would like to convert to png using graphicsmagick. I tried a lot of online converter and similar tools, none was working for me. I have separate tasks on single pages in my pdf document. A colleague suggested to use graphicsmagick. He also provided a code snippet, which I can understand in principle. Everything comes in a shell script, which I never used so far.

My question is: How do I use/execute/call the given code snippet?

This is what I got (I saved it in my working directory as exam.sh):

```sh
function ex {
p=$1
gm convert -trim -density 300x300 file.pdf[$p] /tmp/page.png
H=$(gm identify /tmp/page.png -format "%h")
gm convert page.png -background white -extent 2000x$H auf.png
}
```

Here is what I managed/tried to do:

- Install Ubuntu on Windows 10
- Use the terminal to navigate to my directory (which include a .sh of the code snippet and my file.pdf)
- I can call a script: I created a hello.sh which echos "hello world" (I call it by ´source hello.sh´)
- I can call a script which includes a function with parameters: I created a add.sh (from youtube-video), though I havn't managed to call a function from "outside of the script", i.e. save/activate the function within terminal.
- I installed graphicsmagick and called a one-line, I can do "gm convert -trim -density 300x300 file.pdf[$p] /tmp/page.png" manually.
- I further noticed, there are some issues with editing shell scripts in Windows texteditor, therefore I used "nano" in terminal.

When I try

```sh
source exam.sh
```

It returns "syntax error near unexpected token "

It seems that page is the only parameter I have to give to the function.

```sh
ex 1
```

This doesn't work either.

I appreciate any advice about what I have to include in the script (perhaps specifiy some kind of shell?), what I have to write in the terminal (chmod + x?) in order to tell the terminal my function exists and how to execute the function or give parameters to the function in order to finally get some png.

**Update**

Here is a picture for illustration. I need to crop whatever text/formula is given on a otherwise blank A4-page. The final crop should be 2000 pixel wide. With relative height, dependent on how "long" text/formula/picture is.

[image]

Comment: Why install Ubuntu? GraphicsMagick runs fine under Windows.

Comment: Hi Mark. How can I use the above code in Windows? Regards Marco

Comment: I dislike and don't use Windows, but I'll try and help you without having it... try `gm convert -density 300x300 file.pdf[0] -trim -background white -extent 2000x auf.png` and see if it does what you want.

Comment: I mean for you to just type the above code into your **Command Prompt** after changing directory to where your PDF lives.

Comment: It perfectly works! You combined two commands in one line and I can add the parameter for pages manually. I would have been a nice thing to have a loop going through all the pages. But it's typically about 5-8, so I can also do it by hand. When you post your solution, I will joyfully rate it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it all in one like this, without Ubuntu or shell scripts, just in **Command Prompt**:

```
gm convert -density 300x300 file.pdf[0] -trim -background white -extent 2000x auf.png
```

---

You can probably make a batch file called `EXTRACT.BAT` like this:

```
gm convert -density 300x300 %1[%2] -trim -background white -extent 2000x auf.png
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
EXTRACT FILE.PDF 2
```

to extract page 3 (because first page is page zero) of `FILE.PDF`

Comment: How I can handle the middle part of automatically identifying the height of my png and pass it to the second part of the command? I mean, 2000 should be the fixed length, but height of pngs is relative. Regards

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly. The `-trim` will remove all constant/solid background (presumably white) from your image. Try following that by `-background yellow -extent 2000x3000 result.png` Then try putting `-gravity center` before `-extent`

Comment: I am still unclear what you want, but try `gm convert -density 300x300 file.pdf[0] -trim -resize 2000x auf.png`